# form semantic-ui dropdown selection in angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, semantic-ui, form-control

When I select an item in my dropdown, the empty falues in my form won't change. The formcontrol didn't get the data. Here is my html. I am using `data-value` in getting the selected value of the field

```html
<div id="category" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" [class.error]="formErrors.category">
    <input name="category" type="hidden" formControlName="category">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Select Category...</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of categories" data-value="item._id">{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The dropdown needs jquery to work. I recommend using a jquery-less semantic-ui integration angular for your app: https://github.com/edcarroll/ng2-semantic-ui

Comment: That repository hasn't been updated in months, that's why I don't use them. It starts of as a good intention, but then as the code diverges. Why can't a solution be posted using ng2+ elements?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this. I just used `<select>` instead of `<div>` and used `[attr.value]="item._id"` in the `<option>` to get the selected item's id or value.